# Subclass with GKAgentDelegate not calling agentDidUpdate

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Can anyone tell me why agentDidUpdate() works if I set the delegate to the 'self' in the GameViewController but not when the delegate is set to the Player class, both classes are a GKAgentDelegate. The project can be downloaded here -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=10l44gSKmhiYz21FDYEOKrWKU-y_ScCEL

GameViewController.swift

```
//This works
 func createPlayerAgent()
    {
        let p = Player()
        let agent = GKAgent3D()
        agent.delegate = self
        agent.behavior = GKBehavior()
        agentSystem.addComponent(agent)
    }
//This does not
 func createPlayerAgent()
    {
        let p = Player()
        let agent = GKAgent3D()
        agent.delegate = p
        agent.behavior = GKBehavior()
        agentSystem.addComponent(agent)
    }

@objc func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)
{
    print("renderer")
    // Calculate delta since last update and pass along to the agent system.
    if (self.lastUpdateTime == 0) {
        self.lastUpdateTime = time;
    }

    let delta = time - self.lastUpdateTime
    self.lastUpdateTime = time;
    print(delta)
    self.agentSystem.update(deltaTime: delta)
}

@objc func agentDidUpdate(_ agent: GKAgent3D)
{
    print("agentDidUpdate")
}
```

Player.swift

```
import Foundation
import GameplayKit

class Player:NSObject , GKAgentDelegate
{

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    @objc func agentDidUpdate(_ agent: GKAgent3D)
    {
        print("---agentDidUpdate")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope issue. After the function, the p will be released without saving.

```
   {
    let p = Player()
    let agent = GKAgent3D()
    agent.delegate = p
  }
```

you have to save p to make it survive.

Comment: Thanks for the replay... How do I "save" p?

Comment: Define p as an instance value.

Comment: Thank you that worked... I was creating this as a test project to test another bug, but couldn't even get it to work... My real code is putting p in an array which must be holding onto it.